# MS SQL 2014 - rank

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

I need to rank rows in a way that each customer gets one invoice unless there is a separate invoice value set to 1 - then this very device goes on a separate invoice. Any help much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp (DeviceId INT, CustomerId INT, SeparateInv TINYINT)
INSERT INTO #Tmp VALUES (10, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO #Tmp VALUES (11, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO #Tmp VALUES (12, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #Tmp VALUES (13, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #Tmp VALUES (17, 2, 0)
INSERT INTO #Tmp VALUES (19, 2, 0)

CREATE TABLE #TmpRank (DeviceId INT, CustomerId INT, SeparateInv TINYINT, InvoiceId INT)
INSERT INTO #TmpRank VALUES (10, 1, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO #TmpRank VALUES (11, 1, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO #TmpRank VALUES (12, 1, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO #TmpRank VALUES (13, 1, 1, 3)
INSERT INTO #TmpRank VALUES (17, 2, 0, 4)
INSERT INTO #TmpRank VALUES (19, 2, 0, 4)
```

Regards,
Przemek

Comment: can deviceid be used for ordering?

Comment: What will be your expected output if values (14, 1, 0) are inserted in your table? Can you have such case when invoice is set to 0 from 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerId, CASE WHEN SeparateInv = 1 THEN DeviceId END)
FROM #Tmp
```

The idea here is that for `SeparateInv = 1`, an invoice needs to be generated for each `CustomerId`/`DeviceId` combination, but when `SeparateInv = 0`, an invoice needs to be generated for each `CustomerId`. These can be combined in a single expression: an invoice needs to be generated for each `CustomerId`/`SeparateInvDeviceId` combination, where `SeparateInvDeviceId` is computed from `SeparateInv` and `DeviceId`.